# Do you think is it a good idea to keep the user on a same tab when refreshing the page?

Tags: e-commerce, tab, refresh, page

Do you think is it nice to have or necesary as user expects to stay in the same tab in a navigation when refreshing the page? Here is a demonstration and [the link](https://www.sunweb.nl/vakantie/egypte/rode-zee/el-gouna/hotel-three-corners-rihana-resort-rihana-inn?Participants%5B0%5D%5B0%5D=1989-03-20&Participants%5B0%5D%5B1%5D=1989-03-20&Duration=1-7&Mealplan=AI&Month=2020-01-01&TransportType=Flight&Allocation=2) for the tabs:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. I have added a screenshot to your question to help clarify it. By tabs do you mean the dropdown menu items? If that is the case then they would not need to stay open if the user refreshes the page.

Comment: I see you have added a new screenshot. If the user refreshes the screen when the `Algermeen` tab is selected then yes, it should stay selected.

Comment: ok, thanks @MikePoole for adding the screenshot and your answer, but you don't expect a reset of the page when do yuo refresh a page???

Comment: That is correct. My view would be that the initial state of the page would have the tab selected so it should be like that when they refresh the page too.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep the user where he is expected to be. Not all websites work like this but pages that go the extra step and allows the user to return to his initial state are a big plus.

Comment: In your opinion a user expects to stay at the same tab when refreshing the site?? thanks for your answer Cristian Negraia

Comment: @antonell of course. Why would you even think a user want to be re"directed" when the user re"fresh" the page? This is should be the 101 for every webdev, thats not really a UX secret.

Comment: It is not my opinion it is the norm.

Comment: If it is the norm and 101 for every webdev do you can show me a tab component of any CSS framework where it maintains the user at the same tab when refreshing the browser, I'm searching for that feature.

Comment: It is achieved with js, php or any other languages. Google mantain current tab on refresh.